# Sitecore-Core-Index rebuild at Azure Search for Sitecore 9.0.1 PaaS fails

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-search, paas

I have deployed Sitecore 9.0.1 XP Scaled in Azure PaaS (default, no customization). It is used self-signed certificate and configured with allowInvalidClientCertificates="true" in azuredeploy.parameters.json.

Deployment has proceeded without problems and no errors has been reported. 
I can confirm that all Web App Services works correctly including xConnectColletion and xConnectSearch (certificates are verified)

One of the first post deployment task is to rebuild Sitecore indexes. The challenge is with Sitecore-Core-Index - which is rebuilding very slowly and at the end fails.

In Azure Search (standard tier) I can see 71 000 documents created for Sitecore-Core-Index but there are many errors in the Sitecore logs (as shown bellow). Eventually after several hours running also Sitecore re-indexing interface fail with same error message.

Is this normal behavior ? Why are so many errors in log files?

> 7636 12:17:06 ERROR [Index=sitecore_core_index] Commit failed
>   Exception: System.AggregateException
>   Message: One or more errors occurred.
>   Source: mscorlib
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch batch)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.Commit()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.BadRequestException
>   Message: Error in the request URI, headers, or body
>   Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.UpdateIndex(IndexDefinition indexDefinition)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.SyncRemoteService(IndexDefinition sourceIndexDefinition, IEnumerable`1 incomingFields)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<EnsureIsInSync>b__0()
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Utils.Retryer.RetryPolicy.Execute(Action action)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocumentsImpl(ICloudBatch batch)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch batch)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<PostDocuments>b__0(ISearchService searchService)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
>   Message: {"error":{"code":"","message":"An index with the name 'sitecore-core-index' in service 'myscpaas-as' could not be updated. Error updating index mapping"}}

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the affected index using postman and again rebuild the index.